# I have 100's of password protected excel workbooks (2016) in a specific file location, there are 2 passwords I have to unlock them

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

The below code works for removing 1 known password from multiple excel documents, however if a file in the folder hasn't got the correct password the code will not continue looping through the files left. There are 2 known passwords '191034' and '211034', which cover all the password protected documents in the folder. Is it possible to have 1 piece of code that can loop through the files testing both passwords or will I need to edit the below code so that it will continue looping if password is incorrect and then run a separate code with the other password?

The code:

```
Sub RemovePasswords()

Dim xlBook As Workbook
Dim strFilename As String
Const fPath As String = "C:\Users\ha.smith\Documents\Excel Test\Test Files\CRU\"        'The folder to process, must end with "\"
Const strPassword As String = 211034       'case sensitive
Const strEditPassword As String = "" 'If no password use ""
    strFilename = Dir$(fPath & "*.xls") 'will open xls & xlsx etc
    While Len(strFilename) <> 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set xlBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=fPath & strFilename, _
                                    Password:=strPassword, _
                                    WriteResPassword:=strEditPassword)
        xlBook.SaveAs FileName:=fPath & strFilename, _
                      Password:="", _
                      WriteResPassword:="", _
                      CreateBackup:=False
        xlBook.Close 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        strFilename = Dir$()
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give it a list of passwords and try them all. If one fails try another.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RemovePasswords()
    Dim PasswordList() As Variant
    PasswordList = Array("191034", "211034") ' list your passwords
    
    Const strEditPassword As String = "" 'If no password use ""
    Const fPath As String = "C:\Temp\"        'The folder to process, must end with "\"

    Dim strFilename As String
    strFilename = Dir$(fPath & "*.xls") 'will open xls & xlsx etc
    
    Do While Len(strFilename) <> 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
        Dim strPassword As Variant
        For Each strPassword In PasswordList ' loop through password list and try them all
            On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if wrong password is used
            Dim xlBook As Workbook
            Set xlBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fPath & strFilename, _
                                        Password:=strPassword, _
                                        WriteResPassword:=strEditPassword)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then ' if password was correct save the file
                On Error GoTo 0
                xlBook.SaveAs Filename:=fPath & strFilename, _
                              Password:="", _
                              WriteResPassword:="", _
                              CreateBackup:=False
                xlBook.Close 0
                Exit For ' stop trying other passwords if the correct password was found.
            End If
            
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next strPassword
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        strFilename = Dir$()
    Loop
End Sub
```