# Using Dir with legacy file suffixes

Tags: excel, vba

A recently asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282702) includes the code:

```
strFilename = Dir$(fPath & "*.xls")
```

which is (successfully) used to find files ending **xls** *and **xlsx***.

My question is, why does this find **xlsx** files? It doesn't follow the normal rules of wildcard pattern matching. If I had not seen this used this way I would (and have, repeatedly) use the following for files ending **xls** and **xlsx** :

```
strFilename = Dir$(fPath & "*.xls*")
```

I thought perhaps that pattern matching using `Dir$` automatically added the equivalent of a `*` to the end of the search pattern - but after some testing with `"*.xl"` I can rule that out. Also, to further muddy things, `"*.xls"` will not pick up a **xlsm** or **xlsb** file.

So this would suggest that perhaps `Dir$` has some inbuilt recognition of legacy vs current file suffixes, or an inbuilt list of similarities/synonyms that it should include. But it appears to be one way - as `"*.xlsx"` will not find a **xls** file.

Does anyone know if this is the case? Are there others? Are they documented anywhere? When did it change?

Further to that, if I wanted to craft a `Dir$` that *only* found **xls** files, how might I do that without further checks?

P.S. `Dir` and `Dir$` are interchangeable in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dir in VBA behaves like the Dir-Command on the command shell. And the command shell `Dir` matches both the long name (that is the name you see in Windows) and the short name. If you never heard about that: see for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#short-vs-long-names . Best documentation that I found is https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html - where it simply states *"Wildcards match both the Short and Long filename"*

The extension for short name of a `xlsx`-file is `xls`, that's the reason your Dir finds the files.

As far as I know, there is nothing you can do, you will have to check the real file name manually. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66674917/7599798

Comment: I could have sworn you answered or commented something similar recently. I guess recent = March.

Comment: @BigBen: Yes, you were involved in the discussions. I thought about mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer. Amazing that Microsofts documentation for `Dir` doesn't mention something so significant as to break the (apparent) logic. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function